# javascript, why not remove var keyword?

Tags: javascript, scope, var

almost all javascript books said that

> always use var keyword when you
>   declare variables, because without
>   var, the variable will be declared as
>   global variable.

then, why not remove var keyword, make default declaration as local scope?
like Python, if you want to use global variables, you write:

```
global foo;
```

we use local variables almost all the time, don't we?
is there a good reason? 
Thanks for any help.

---

edit:
Thanks for all your help, I thought there must be a good reason shows that using var is better, so I was not attempting to change the language what it was like.

Comment: ok,,if people don't use local variables more than global's, why "always use var keyword"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
function A() {
    var foo; // variable in the scope of function A
    function B() {
        foo; // variable still in the scope of function A
    }
}
```

If the choice was "Narrowest scope" or "Global scope" then this wouldn't be possible.

Comment: thank you. I didn't see this. but use "var" or not are just two styles, if we define "no var" is "var exists" then, all the meaning keep the same, it just looks different.

Answer (score 6):

```
var globalInt = 5;

function Hello()
{
    // Hey, give me back my var keyword!
    // I want to assign a global existing variable
    globalInt = 7; 
}
```

Another point is there is no easy way to **remove** something from JavaScript. Every feature (even hacks) is already used on thousands of sites and removing features will break those sites. JavaScript can only be extended. Or new JS should be created which will be incompatible with previous versions.

Comment: but no, if there is no declaration with global keyword, the globalInt in function Hello will be local variable. I think it's better.

Comment: @netroyal, do you mean introducing another keyword with opposite meaning just because `var` behavior is used more often and it should be made default?

Comment: yeah, I thought mean it, but I wonder if there is a reason that using var keyword is better?

Comment: using global variables also slows down function speeds. the javascript processor scans the function for variables and builds the stack frame accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

This is just the way the language was designed.  If a variable is auto-allocated it is allocated in the global scope.

It makes a lot of sense if you think about it.  What scope should a variable be allocated in?  The compiler has no way of knowing the programmers goal with an explicit declaration

For better or worse JS was designed the way it was. I believe allowing variables to auto-declare was a mistake but given that it exists in JS it makes sense to have them be global since JS does not have block level scope.

Comment: Why does the compiler have no way of knowing?  JavaScript is a block-based language, and it's completely reasonable to assume that the programmer intends for a variable to be scoped in the block it was declared in (on par with how most other languages work).  Anything meant to be global just needs to be declared outside of a block.

Comment: @aroth : Sort of aroth -- but closures get complicated quickly.  Just think about some of the more complicated cases.

Comment: @Hogan, thanks for pointing that out. I thought that was a typo and answered for the opposite :)

Comment: @aroth, it's easy to say that way until you'll get a global variable defined in third-party JS file.

Comment: but without global keyword, compiler should treat all the variables in local scope, is it a better way? thank you for your help. I think it is just the way the language was designed too.

Comment: @netroyal : For better or worse JS was designed the way it was.  I believe allowing variables to auto-declare was a mistake but given that it exists in JS it makes sense to have them be global since JS does not have block level scope.

Answer (score 1):

using var keyword inside a function declares the variable in local scope, hence preventing overwriting of any global variable. Idea is to play safe, and use var. If you know what you are doing (100% sure that you will not overwrite any global variable) feel free to discard var.

Comment: I think this was the point of the original question -- if local scope is better why require the `var` keyword to perform what should be a default action.

Comment: I agree with your opinion. This is the way javascript was designed.

Answer (score 1):

OK, i'll try to explain how it works again. There is a ECMAScript's `Global` object, which is "root" of everything else. In browsers `window` object implements `Global`. So:

```
function assert( condition, message ) {
  if ( !condition ) 
      if ( typeof message != 'undefined' ) alert( message ); 
      else alert( 'Free Consulting just talks rubbish' );
}

// assuming global scope
assert( this == window, 'noes!' ); // and Global context

var spam = 'for all you python lovers'; // becomes a property of Global
assert( spam == window.spam, 'there not much spam in it' ); // same

function eggs () { // becomes a method of Global actually
  assert( spam == window.spam, 'shut up!' ); // unqualified spam available here through closure
  assert( arguments.callee == window.eggs ); // and again
}
eggs();
```

*Mrs Conclusion*: JavaScript is distinct language with own specific traits, so do not apply other language knowledge to JS (it makes Douglas Crockford a sad panda :)

Comment: alert(this === window); var spam = 'spam'; alert(spam === window.spam); function eggs(){alert(spam === window.spam); alert(arguments.callee === window.eggs);}eggs();

Comment: what are you talking about? I read your words carefully , but do you read my question carefully?thanks anyway.

Comment: @netroyal read again about closures, and other languages impression

Comment: OK, I think your code's style is good in a real project.Thank you for giving this. I just didn't understand what was your meaning. thanks again.